# Batch - Get Requests from different Microservices

Tags: rest, get, microservices

I am dividing a monolithic service to a microservice architecture. What I have done is separate the services and now the REST call is distributed but the problem is if I call a `service A` which returns 10000 instances and it is dependent on some other `service B`, so call comes to `service A` and for each instance, call goes to `service B` to get its data, so converting a single call to 10000 additional calls so now the call takes alot of time.

I want to make multiple Get Requests in a single request.

What I have searched is to use batch requests to POST different instances, but this is recommended on Creating & Updating multiple instances together. Can this be done for getting information as well?

And is there any other way to do it?

Edit: A similar use case as to mine e.g. There are two services one service gets the details of students and the other gets the details of teachers. In teachers table there is student's ID that it teaches not as a foreign key but a simple key, Now in the UI for the teacher, it shows the teacher details and the student ID and student names and class it belongs to, so for getting the student name and class details, I would have to call the student's service with the student's ID.

Comment: Why do you need to request additional information from `service B`? Can you give a concrete situation?

Comment: Edited the question with example

Comment: Do you use an event-driven architecture? If yes, do `service B` expose those events (for exemple at a REST endpoint like `/events`)?

Answer (score 3):

The pattern you are looking for is [API Gateway](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html). Sometimes also called "Edge" or "EdgeService". It can be used to as a single entrypoint to your cluster and to aggregate service call results. Other use cases include central authentication and/or authorization as well as routing, monitoring and resiliency.

With aggregation an API Gateway will potentially allow you to decouple your services (but of course it also depends on what your use case actually is, since you didn't give any details).

Some people only route external calls through a gateway, others route also internal calls through the gateway.

Here some technologies to look into:

[Zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki) from the Netflix stack. You have write a filter for aggregation. See [this](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki/Writing-Filters) document.

[Amazon API gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) - If you are running on AWS. You would typically use your own lambda service for aggregation.

[Kong](https://getkong.org/about/). Doesn't have native aggregation support, but you can forward to a separate aggregation service that you provide.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it more clear, a Microservice itself, fulfilles its business responsibility without depending any other service(s).  In your case 'ServiceA' is not a microservice but it's just a service because it dependent to another some service to complete its job.

So do you able to change the contracts of the service? For example modify ServiceB input & outputs to return/maintain 100 instances per call rather than 1. It will provide making more less request and taking less time. It makes sense that if you develop a batch-behaviour application/service, your dependent-services which manages collective data will help you to saving network and total runtime cost. But in this case 'serviceA' will not be a microservice.

So if you really determined to make it a real "microservice" just combine service A and service B together. Microservice concept is not about making a service small as "micro". A Microservice just responsible for doing its job that related to its business domain without depending another domain/service/module etc.

Combining 2 services which are in same domain to 1 and process some bulk data in this service does not violate microservice concept.

Comment: "a Microservices itself, fulfilles his business responsibility without depending any other service" - I do not agree. There are so many situations when a ms needs data from another... it is called `dependency. It can not be eliminated. It can be inversed and minimized and delayed but not eliminated.

Comment: What are you talk about is called SOA architecture by some authorities. I know microservices are already is a subset of SOA. But generally some people agree that a microservice can be dependent to another but another think that a microservice can't be dependent to another becuase when other one is unavaliable , it cant do its job. I agree with second group and you are in first group. That's it:) So that's why  there's something like that Micrservice orchestration (in communication manner -not about deployment- ) , API Gateway etc.

Comment: Microservices are a subset of SOA. I give you an example: authorization. It is (in any good architecture) in another microservice and all other client microservices use it. What are you talking about is called "resilience" (as oposed to cascade failure) and there are technics to increase it (like caching or pre-loading of data).

Comment: As I said, microservice concept have different meanings for all of us. The concept do not have certain rules that strongly typed somewhere.. You make assumption that "in any good arch.".

Comment: Some people think that crosscutting and common dependency concerns should be handled in m-service orchestration layer. So i would make auth controls in orhcestration layer. So if serviceA is being called, first orchestration layer will check access via AuthService then, if auth ok, request will be made to serviceA.(like an aspect) In this approach, if AuthService changes,( assume that u were using LDAP an now different security module which service contract is different from previous one)  you dont have to make changes in your all services. You will only change orchestration layer integration.

Comment: *Perfect*. But, in your exemple, what happens if `AuthService` is down?

Comment: Down case is not a comparing situation. You can use circuit breaker etc. pattern in both approach. If you cut all cables of your machine, whatever architecture you use, your services will be unavaliable. The point is that seperating concerns in logical manner.  If you touch all consumer services when you change your producer services it means there's some high coupling. and you have to deploy all of them each time producer changes.

Comment: Again, I do not agree. **Depending on the business**, if you use an architecture like the one in question and *afford stale data* and use data duplication, even if `service B` is down, `service A` can still work. If you use an event-driven architecture then data duplication is as *simple* as subscribing to the right events. Think about authorization (being `service B`): why should  `service A` still not work if the administrator can't update the permissions to some resource?

Comment: You seem like a nice guy, I don't want to offend you :) I'm watching right now at this video, you should check it out: https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/8207-the-long-sad-history-of-microservices

Comment: I finally agree.

Comment: Thanks for the link. For our project I'm watching, reading, discussing lots of resources since September 2016. 
Only thing I can summarize that it really depending on the business as you said. That's why I said in my first answer that 
there's different approaches and different thoughts about microservice architecture implementation. I can share lots of resources
that support my point of view. But it does not make sense. Your approach is not wrong one neither mine. Really it depends on the business.

Comment: And there's nothing to be offended :) Our differences and discussing them make us stronger. Thanks for the conversation.

Comment: If you want to discuss further you can contact me on skype